# Changing font values from PT to PX in Flash CS4

Tags: flash, user-interface, properties, flash-cs4

Just bought Flash CS4 Pro, and for some reason the font sizing is no default Points not Pixels. I can't see anywhere to change this. Anyone got any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

in my experience i didn't found any difference, for example if in my photoshop design de fonts were in px and the fonts in flash were in pt.

you can change all the font line metrics separately if you wish using the TextLineMetrics class

[TextLineMetrics class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html)